# Convert projects from compact framework .NET to the full framework .Net

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, compact-framework

So I have a big c# solution containing 120 projects. The solution doesn’t contain a user interface and is compiled to support both compact framework and the full framework. The solution is in Visual Studio 2005 format.

I would like to remove the support for Windows CE and convert it all to target the full framework and open it in Visual Studio 2010.

What I want to do is remove the support for compact framework from the whole solution.

How should I proceed? Is it possible to just convert the projects to the full framework?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the end I had to edit manually every csproj file in the solution.
I removed the information’s related to targeting the compact framework et replaced it with the needed info to target the full framework.

It wasn't very fun but now it works.

Thanks

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I wish you had mentioned exactly what you had removed and what you had replaced it with.

Answer (score 7):

I created a dummy solution containing a WinForms project and a Device WinForms project. Then I compared to two. Useful for me as I'm hoping to port to Windows 10 at some point now they've got it running on ARM devices :D

1) Remove the "ProjectTypeGuids", "PlatformFamilyName", "PlatformID", "OSVersion", "DeployDirSuffix", "NativePlatformName", "NoStdLib", "NoConfig" elements.

2) Remove references to "$(PlatformFamilyName)".

3) Remove any "RequiredTargetFramework" elements.

4) If it exists, the line containing:-

..Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CompactFramework.CSharp.targets"..

needs to become...

..Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets"..

If it doesn't exist, you need to add it in.

5) Remove the entire "ProjectExtensions" element.

et viola.. it converts... Now if only it would build :/

Edit:

A little bit of tweaking and it built and ran OK. After a little over an hours work my CF WinForms warehousing app is running on Windows 10.

Comment: This one worked for me. Thanks for listing all items, eyes were going blurry trying to compare old proj to a working equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Open the solution with WS2010, click on each project file -> Properties -> Application tab, then you can select the target framework. Should work.

Comment: uo, I almost forget, 120 projects. Maybe he can do it with one project, see with notepad++ or something the change on the project file and try a massive replace. Suicidal, maybe, but maybe works

Comment: I started thinking after I posted that... Could a VS macro do it? Or maybe there's already an add-in.

Comment: @Michael Itzoe nice, let us know if you find something!